# Bash array print, but only 23 lines at a time.

Tags: bash

Okay I'm trying to conform to some standards for a project. I am only allowed to print out 23 lines at a time. I have fed the files of a directory into an array and know how to print it out.

```
        LIST=(`ls`)
        len=${#LIST[*]}
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
        echo "$i: ${LIST[$i]}"
        let i++
        done
```

I'm trying to only allow it to print out 23 items at one time, then ask for a user input to continue,

```
         read -n1 -rsp $'Press any key to continue \n'
```

And then the user will type the number of the file that they want to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to use an array ?

Comment: Don't use `ls` like this. `LIST=( * )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that:

```bash
LIST=(`ls`)
len=${#LIST[*]}
i=1
while [ $i -lt $len ]
do
  echo "$i: ${LIST[$i]}"
  if [ `expr $i % 23` == 0 ]
  then
    read -n1 -rsp $'Press any key to continue \n'
  fi
  let i++
done
```

i.e. you condition placed in:

```bash
if [ `expr $i % 23` == 0 ]
then
    . . . 
fi
```

also note `i=1` cause `0 % N` always gives zero

Comment: that is so beautiful, I never even thought of pausing it for divisions of 23. Thank you!

Comment: I'm searching now, is there a way to do if [ \`expr ($i+1) % 23` ==0 } to account for the array starting at 0?

Comment: When using `expr` place spaces between agruments (yeh they are arguments), for you case it would be `expr \( $i + 1 \) % 23`

Comment: Thank you once again, thought that might be it, but was having a hard time googling examples

Comment: `expr` is not needed for arithmetic in `bash` (or any POSIX shell). `if [ $(( i % 23 )) -eq 0 ]` for full POSIX compatibility, or just `if (( i % 23 == 0 ))` in `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this BASH script:

```
n=22
arr=(*)
for ((i=0; i<=${#arr[@]}; i+=n)); do
   echo "${arr[@]:$i:$n}"
   read -n1 -p 'Press any key to continue...'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split it into dual loops.

Also note, don't use `ls` in scripts.

```
LIST=( * )
len="${#LIST[@]}"
for((i=0; i<$len; i+=23)); do
    [[ $i > 1 ]] && read -n1 -rsp $'Press any key to continue \n'
    for((j=0, k=i; j<23 && k<$len; ++j, ++k)); do
        echo "[$i + $j] $k: ${LIST[$k]}"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` command can be used in place of a loop here.

```
tmp=( "${LINES[@]}" )
start=1
while (( ${#tmp[@]} -gt 0 )); do
    printf "%s\n" "${tmp[@]:0:23}" | nl -v $start
    tmp=( "${tmp[@]:23}" )
    ((start+=23))
    read -n1 -rsp $'Press any key to continue \n' 
done
```

`tmp` is used to avoid destroying `LINES` unnecessarily. The `printf` along with the substring expansion operator on `tmp` is used to print 23 lines at a time, piped through
`nl` for numbering. The `start` variable can be used to number the lines continuously, rather than printing each batch as lines 1–23.